# Robot gripper passes through object to be grasped

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo version 2.2.3
I am trying to implement a grasping algorithm on my custom robot but it passes through the object instead of grasping it. I've checked all the collision tags in both urdfs (robot's and object's) and they are standard, potential problems that I can think of:-

Collision geometry is not correct: Highly unlikely as the robot is using its meshes as geometry and the object is simple cylinder.

Controllers of joint angles of the robot are not right: I've used standard ros_control position controllers and what I've noticed is that on echoing joint_states topic I can see position and velocity but effort is zero for all messages. I configured controllers referencing from master of robot programming book and even in their example the arm passes through the floor.

Arm breaks when I reset the gazebo world: Might have some correlation

If any of these conditions imply something in the context of gripper passing through the object then please help.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13683/robot-gripper-passes-through-object-to-be-grasped/) by [rilch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2676/rilch/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rilch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2676/rilch/) on 2016-06-20**:
Bravo they are all scattered and not in right places thank you! I'll try to arrange them properly and see if it works.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-06-20**:
I converted the comment to an answer, just accept it if that ended up being the problem. Good luck!

**Comment by [rilch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2676/rilch/) on 2016-06-20**:
It works! I feel so stupid. I did not check the visual origins with collision origins and the equally quilty company which generated this urdf charged 12k for the arm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Have you made sure the collisions are where you expect them to be in Gazebo? Right-click the model and choose View->Collisions

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0